# Xpath2.0 selecting first and last occurance of string with iteration

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have this tree:

```
<Events>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314022</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>ABC1234</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314023</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>ABC1234</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314024</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>ABC1234</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314022</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314023</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Properties>
   <Property Descriptor=100>1378314024</Property>
   <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
 </Properties>

</Events>
```

I'm iterating at this level: `Events/Properties`

How can I have only the FIRST and LAST occurrence of each `Property Descriptor = 200` and its respective `Property Descriptor = 100`?

I've tried so far:

- Iteration: `Events/Properties`
- Select:
  `Property[@Descriptor=200])[last()] or
  Property[@Descriptor=200])[first()]`

but with no success.

OUTPUT should look like this [I'm showing it in HTML, iterating in the ROW level]:

```
P100        | P200
1378314022  | ABC1234
1378314024  | ABC1234
1378314022  | 123456
1378314024  | 123456
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 this would be easy with `for-each-group`, grouping by the 200 value and taking the first and last members of each group.  But in pure XPath (not XSLT) you need to think laterally.

If the groups are always contiguous as you've shown here (i.e. all the `ABC1234` entries are adjacent to one another, and all the `123456` entries are adjacent to one another) then this boils down to wanting every `Properties` element *P* that does not have an immediately preceding *and* an immediately following sibling `Properties` element with the same `200` value as *P*.  I.e. you want to *iterate* over

```
Events/Properties[not(
  (
    Property[@Descriptor="200"] =
    preceding-sibling::Properties[1]/Property[@Descriptor="200"]
  ) and (
    Property[@Descriptor="200"] =
    following-sibling::Properties[1]/Property[@Descriptor="200"]
  )
)]
```

and then *select* the `Property[@Descriptor="100"]` and `Property[@Descriptor="200"]` from each of the resulting `Properties` elements.

You've tagged your question "xpath-2.0" but this expression is also valid in XPath 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your elegant solution and detailed explanation. I've applied ***Events/Properties[count(for $me in (Property[@Descriptor="200"]) return (preceding-sibling::Properties[1][Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me], following-sibling::Properties[1][Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me])) != 2]*** to my application but the iteration seems not to be working. There are nodes before Events but I added them to the iteration. Could I do it?

Comment: I also tried ***//Events/Properties[count(for $me in (Property[@Descriptor="200"]) return (preceding-sibling::Properties[1][Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me], following-sibling::Properties[1][Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me])) != 2]*** and it didn't work. :(

Comment: @Dalek "Didn't work" - what output did you get?  Do you get more than you expected or do you get nothing at all?  Does the real document include any namespaces, as if so then you'll need to take account of this in your XPath expressions by binding appropriate prefixes.  Exactly how you do this depends on what tool/library/programming language you're using, which you haven't stated in the question.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information. 1 - I get no output at all. 2 - I'm using a proprietary tool that queries an XML document and shows the information in an HTML page. This iteration is being added to a row and the select is added to a cell inside it. At the moment there's no row visible so it's not iterating at all.

Comment: @Dalek You haven't answered the question about namespaces.  Does your input XML have an `xmlns="..."` in it anywhere?  If so you will need to account for the namespace, either by binding it to a prefix in whatever way your tool supports, or by ignoring it by prefixing all your element selectors in the XPaths with `*:`, i.e. `*:Events/*:Properties[..... preceding-sibling::*:Properties[1] ... ]` etc.

Comment: Sorry I haven't answered it properly. The XML file does have 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"'. I've added the changes you mentioned but the result is still the same. I've even tried ***//*:Events/*:Properties[count(for $me in (*:Property[@Descriptor="200"]) return (preceding-sibling::*:Properties[1][*:Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me], following-sibling::*:Properties[1][*:Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me])) != 2]***

Comment: @Dalek all I can suggest now is that you break things down bit by bit and do your own debugging - start with `//Events/Properties` (which should give you all the properties elements), then try `//Events/Properties[for $me in (.) return $me]` which should give you the same, and gradually add in the various parts until it breaks.  I can't really help further as I don't have your "proprietary tool" so I can't reproduce the problem.  All I can say is that my original solution definitely worked correctly in an XSLT 2.0 test harness.

Comment: //Events/Properties returns all properties but //Events/Properties[for $me in (.) return $me] returns nothing. What does it mean?

Comment: @Dalek that suggests to me that your XPath engine is in fact only XPath 1.0, not 2.0.  I'll see if I can re-write this expression in a 1.0-compatible form.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've opened a new question because you answer for this one is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079359/xpath-replace-for-statement/23080238?noredirect=1#23080238

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure which answer you are looking for, but here I will give you two examples. One of them should probably fit your needs.

I used the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Events>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314022</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">ABC1234</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD2356</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">25689</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314023</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">ABC1234</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD2356</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">25689</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314024</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">ABC1234</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD2356</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">25689</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314022</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">123456</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD2356</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">25689</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314023</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">123456</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD2356</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">25689</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314024</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">123456</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD2356</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">25689</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
</Events>
```

When I use the next XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Properties">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Property[@Descriptor = '100'][1]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Property[@Descriptor = '100'][last()]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Property[@Descriptor = '200'][1]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Property[@Descriptor = '200'][last()]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT also has a iteration over the `Properties` element, within that `Properties` element it gets the first and the last occurence of each provided `Descriptor`. The result would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Events>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314022</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">ABC1234</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314023</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">ABC1234</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314024</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">ABC1234</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314022</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">123456</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314023</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">123456</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314024</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">123456</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
</Events>
```

If you want to get the last en first occurence over all the `Properties` the XSLT should be slightly different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Events">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Properties>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="(Properties/Property[@Descriptor = '100'])[1]" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="(Properties/Property[@Descriptor = '100'])[last()]" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="(Properties/Property[@Descriptor = '200'])[1]" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="(Properties/Property[@Descriptor = '200'])[last()]" />
            </Properties>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result would then be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Events>
    <Properties>
        <Property Descriptor="100">1378314022</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="100">MD75632</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">ABC1234</Property>
        <Property Descriptor="200">5632</Property>
    </Properties>
</Events>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I'm actually only using Xpath for this... I've got to iterate at Events level [that's one XPath expression] and select the value [that's another XPath expression]. This has to be dynamic also so that's why I tried Property[@Descriptor=200])[last()] or
Property[@Descriptor=200])[first()]. Sorry for not making that clear in the question!