# XPath replace FOR statement

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XPath (Thanks to Ian Roberts' answer in SO [Xpath2.0 selecting first and last occurance of string with iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060770/xpath2-0-selecting-first-and-last-occurance-of-string-with-iteration/)) :

```
Events/Properties[
  count(
    for $me in (Property[@Descriptor="200"]) return
      (preceding-sibling::Properties[1][Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me],
       following-sibling::Properties[1][Property[@Descriptor="200"] = $me])
  ) != 2
]
```

The XPath is great but the tool I'm using is not accepting `for` statement.

How could I rewrite this XPath to avoid this issue [without `for` statement]?

Comment: So what is the tool you're using?

Comment: A proprietary reporting tool... has no specification related to Xpath to be honest. Just uses XPath as a way of selecting nodes in a XML document.

Comment: So I'm assuming you want an XPath 1.0 expression, because if your tool chockes on 2.0 then it might be not modern enough for it.

Comment: Note that I've simplified my answer a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input is ordered (that's the important bit!), you can do it by issuing these XPath 1.0 expressions:

First ones in group:

```
//Properties[
  Property/@Descriptor = 200
  and not(
    Property = preceding-sibling::*/Property[@Descriptor = 200]
  )
]
```

last ones in group:

```
//Properties[
  Property/@Descriptor = 200
  and not(
    Property = following-sibling::*/Property[@Descriptor = 200]
  )
]
```

You can go from there and select `Property[@Descriptor = 100]` or `Property[@Descriptor = 200]` individually.

---

You can combine both expressions into one:

```
//Properties[
  Property/@Descriptor = 200 and ( 
    not(
      Property = preceding-sibling::*/Property[@Descriptor = 200]
    ) or not(
      Property = following-sibling::*/Property[@Descriptor = 200]
    ) 
  )
]
```

You would get a list of `<Properties>` pairs (first and last ones in their respective groups), except for groups that are one element long. That means there's no guarantee that you would not get an even number of nodes returned.